# Search for numbers and do some math evalutation on them in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, replace, windows-7, sublimetext2

Is it possible to look for numbers in a text file and do some math evaluation on them in the replace feature ? Using a built-in feature or a plugin.

For example, suppose I have following text file content :

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And I want to increment each number, for a result like this :

```
2
3
4
5  
6
```

Comment: why dont you just use Excel instead?

Comment: The case I gave is just an example, what about when the patterns are complex and need regex search for specific numbers ?

Comment: Last time I checked regex was pattern matching engine, not programming language. But you are more than welcome to write a plugin of your own that would 1) Pull the matching words (digits?) with a pattern, 2) Do what you need to do with them, 3) replace them with original values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/) contains a Sublime Text 2 package that would do something like this. Some quick searching found [Evaluate](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Evaluate) and [Selection Evaluator](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Selection%20Evaluator) (which is deprecated) which can both replace the selection by doing something external and may be workable for your use case.

The [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) package also has an [Evaluate Math Expression](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/evaluate-math/) functionality that may be useful, if you happen to already use Emmet in your workflow. A note on Emmet is that it's fairly intrusive and steals your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, so extra configuration may be required to keep other things working as you expect.

Although you've tagged Sublime Text 2 specifically, I'd also point out that the latest development versions of Sublime Text 3 have among their list of new features something like the following, which may be what you want.

[image: Using the Arithmetic command]

Here I use a simple regex that matches all numbers, then use the new `Arithmetic` command to manipulate the values using an arbitrary expression.

Something to note is that this is a feature added in the latest development series and hasn't made its way to stable yet. As such if you want to use it right now you need to have an ST3 license (only licensed users can use development versions).

Comment: How do you enter a command in the replacement field?  It's not clear in your animation how one does it.  Thanks.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho that is detailed in [how to add different number at end of multi line edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54412073/814803). There is also a video that walks through that and more extended uses, [The Super Powers of the Secret Arithmetic Command](https://youtu.be/taLCxwgcrVk)

Comment: I eventually upgraded to Sublime Text 3 and this is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks