# how to add different number at end of multi line edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

Having trouble finding a way to do this, maybe it is not even possible?

In my case, for testing flow of if-statements/user-interaction, am temporarily adding 40 lines of `console.log('trigger-fired-1');` throughout our code.

However, to tell them apart would like each to end with a different number, so in this case, numbers one to forty like so:

[image]

In the screen recorded gif, to replicate what I am going for, all I did was copy/paste the numbers one to nine. What I really would like is a shortcut key to generate those numbers at the end for me to eliminate that step of typing out each unique number.

Am primarily coding in Visual Studio Code or Sublime Text, and in some cases shortcuts are similar, or at least have same support but for different shortcut keys.

Answer (score 12):

There are a few extensions that allow you to do this:

- [Text Pastry](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jkjustjoshing.vscode-text-pastry)
- [Increment Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albymor.increment-selection)
- [NumberMonger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=softwareape.numbermonger)

Comment: Thank you! Will give these a try for Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 10):

For Sublime Text, the solution to this problem is the internal `Arithmetic` command. Something similar may or may not be available in VS Code (possibly with an extension of some sort) but I'm not familiar enough with it to say for sure.

This command allows you to provide an expression of some sort to apply to all of the cursor locations and/or selected text.

By way of demonstration, here's the example you outlined above:

[image: Sample Arithmetic Example]

The expression you provide is evaluated once for every selection/caret in the buffer at the time, and the result of the expression is inserted into the buffer (or in the case of selected text, it replaces the selection). Note also that when you invoke this command from the input panel (as in the screen recording) the panel shows you a preview of what the expression output is going to be.

The special variable `i` references the selection number; selections are numbered starting at `0`, so the expression `i + 1` has the effect of inserting the selection numbers starting at 1 instead of 0.

The special variable `x` refers to the text in a particular selection instead. That allows you to select some text and then transform it based on your expression. An example would be to use `x * 2` immediately after the above example (make sure all of the selections are still present and wrapping the numbers) to double everything.

You can use both variables at once if you like, as well as anything in the Python `math` library, for example `math.sqrt(i)` if you want some really esoteric logs.

The example above shows the command being selected from the command palette interactively, where the expression automatically defaults to the one that you want for your example (`i + 1`).

If you want to have this as a key binding, you can bind a key to the `arithmetic` command and provide the expression directly. For example:

```json
{
    "keys": ["super+a"],
    "command": "arithmetic",
    "args": {
        "expr": "i+1"
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you! Will be using this for my Sublime Text development

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...
its not like sublime

but works g
https://github.com/kuone314/VSCodeExtensionInsertSequence

Answer (score 0):

copy of this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/64083371/5902698

You want to have a number at each row that you selected, but not the same. For exemple, you select 5 cursors and you want to write 1 2 3 4 5.

select your 5 cursors (maybe you can use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>)
[image]

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select arithmetic
[image]

Because you have 5 cursors, it propose 1 2 3 4 5
[image]
[image]

If you want you can change your step of iteration
[image]

Or start from an other number than 1
[image]

Add even numbers
[image]