# Regex find replace with multiplier in Atom or Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I would like to replace all occurrences of a particular set of numeric values with their respective scalar multiples using the regex find/replace function in Atom or Sublime, preferably Atom.

For e.g., convert

```
headerContainer: {
    fontSize:'1em',
    padding: '1.5rem',
},
```

to

```
headerContainer: {
    fontSize: 16,
    padding: 24,
},
```

My regex find:

```
(')([\d.]+)r?em(')
```

My regex replace possibility:

```
$2 \* 16
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @sean This is within an IDE Maybe change part of it to (\d+\.\d*)r?em - not sure what ') and (' are doing. That may be IDE specific Regex. I know you are wanting to remove the quotes. But normally I'd be doing things with names capture groups in something like Python/JavaScript

Comment: @JGFMK—no, I'm asking what language the code is in, as it's not CSS

Comment: May be SCSS - not sure..

Comment: I am not sure what `$2 \* 16` relates to - changing 1 to 16 for em vs 1.5 to 24 also seems odd. You would have to be doing some maths to convert the number of the regex result. Does browser allow that? Sounds more like a script...

Comment: Like percentages, em and rem units are relative units—their scalar equivalents are dependent upon other values. In some cases 1em may be 16px, but 1em may just as easily be 24px or 13px or 19.1473px. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: I understand em/rem CSS... but how a find and replace in an IDE are going to accommodate that are what's baffling me. How would a parameterised regex would work. Would have to see something in operation to get it to register..

Comment: You cannot do math in string replacement patterns. You need a full-fledged language with an access to callback. Python might turn out the easiest here.

Comment: @JGFMK my comments not mentioning you are directed to the author of the question

Comment: @sean - It's irrelevant.  I have to give an example.  An editor is independent of language.  However that's a basic JS object pattern used for styles in React-Native.

Comment: @JGFMK - In this case I'm limited to the editor's regex functionality.  Therefore no access to callbacks.  I was hoping that there was some means to escape some hidden arithmetic characters.

Seems like a common use case where eliminating 'em's would simultaneously require a scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew - I fear you may be correct.  But what if it were replacing an integer?  Would it be possible then?  Because that would simply be 2 operations.

Comment: @AdrianBartholomew You can't expect to match `2`  and replace it with the result of `*16` (32). You can only hardcode such replacements. In Notepad++, you may use Python Script plugin to do what you want, but a normal Python scipt would be better.

Comment: Procedural Text Edit is able to do math on numbers but isn't integrated in those editors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments on your question, this is not directly possible with just a regular expression find and replace, but it is nonetheless possible in Sublime Text (and maybe Atom if it has similar functionality) using built in functionality.

To do this in Sublime, you want to use a combination of a `Find All` to select all of the text and the built in `Arithmetic` command to alter the selection. The specifics of how the `Arithmetic` command works can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54412073/814803), so I'm not going to cover that here.

To do what you want here, do the following:

1. Use the `Find` panel (or the `Replace` panel) to search for the regex `'[\d.]+r?em'`, but click the `Find All` button in the panel, which will select all of the matching items in the buffer.
2. Use the `Arithmetic` command from the command palette and enter the expression `round(float(x.strip("'rem"))*16)` and press enter to run the command.

The expression here modifies the selected text (`x`) by removing the single quotes and the characters `rem`, turns the resulting string into a floating point value, does the multiplication, and then rounds the value.

The result of that is something like this:

[image: Example of technique in action]

Comment: Beautiful.  I got it done with Atom in a roundabout way.
I first replaced '1.5rem' with 1.5*16.  Then did another search for all such patterns.  Option-Enter put them in the buffer and then Shift-Command-Y evaluated them.

I never bothered to try Sublime as I didn't think it would be any different.  Just tried your solution and it's a far superior one and so will accept it. - when I'm able to.

Maybe there's an Arithmetic plugin for Atom.
Good job!